# Cannot return null for non-nullable field in graphql

Tags: graphql, apollo

I have a Apollo server query that returns an array of movies based on a `userId`value:

```
  moviesFromUser: async (root, args) => {
    const movie = await prisma.movie.findMany({
      where: {userId: args.userId},
    });
    console.log(movie);
    return movie;
  },
```

In the sandbox I have a query to fetch the movies based on `userId`:

```
query moviesFromUser {
  moviesFromUser(userId: 1) {
    original_title
  }
}
```

When I run this query I see the movies I've requested in the console log of the Apollo server:

```
[
  {
    id: 251,
    original_title: 'Dune',
    tmdb_id: 2,
    poster_path: 'cDbNAY0KM84cxXhmj8f0dLWza3t.jpg',
    userId: 1
  },
  {
    id: 252,
    original_title: 'Batman',
    tmdb_id: 3,
    poster_path: 'asdadsdasadsadsdas.jpg',
    userId: 1
  }
]
```

But the actual response in the playground is:

> "message": "Cannot return null for non-nullable field Movie.original_title."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resolved the issue thanks to shankie_san his answer here > [Apollo GraphQL "Cannot return null for non-nullable field Mutation.createUser"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56538163/apollo-graphql-cannot-return-null-for-non-nullable-field-mutation-createuser)

My issue was that this resolver:

```
  moviesFromUser: async (root, args) => {
    const movie = await prisma.movie.findMany({
      where: {userId: args.userId},
    });
    console.log(movie);
    return movie;
  },
```

Is returning an array of movies, but my schema was returning a single movie object:

```
  type Query {
    moviesFromUser(userId: Int!): Movie
  }
```

Changing `moviesFromUser(userId: Int!): Movie` to `moviesFromUser(userId: Int!):  [Movie]` fixed the issue since now my schema reflects my resolver.

Comment: Exactly what was up with mine! thank you!